# SQL Server Maintenance Plan Problem (reorganise/rebuild indexes)

Tags: sql-server

I'm having a strange problem with a SQL Server Maintenance Plan. It's set up to run a Reorganise Indexes and Rebuild Indexes, the history shows it has succeeded, but the fragmentation is still bad and requires me to manually intervene to fix them.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Which version of SQL? Is it a custom scripted job or was it made using the Maintenance Plan tools? Could you provide the script/tools you used?

Answer (score 1):

You should reorganize or rebuild indexes, not both. Rebuilding an index drops the index and creates a new one, so rebuilding will fix any fragmentation problems. [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189858.aspx).

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't really address why the indexes are remaining fragmented after both operations run.